# iPhone app backend obligation timeframe

Tags: iphone, app-store

I'm developing a iPhone application that will use a Google App Engine backend and planning to sell my application for $1 on the App Store.

I feel there is a risk that my Google App Engine cost exceeds my revenue from the application and therefore it is not possible to keep the app backend going in long term.

The question is - For how long am I obligated to run the backend? It is not possible to run the backend forever, so how long do I have to have it available?

Comment: I'm removing your GAE tag, since your question pertains only to App Store licensing terms.

Comment: Why are you using a backend anyway?

Comment: Also, this isn't really related to programming, per-se, so it's offtopic for SO.

Comment: Sorry for the offtopic. I'm using a backend because the idea of the application is that users can share and collaborate with data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have options other than just an upfront licence cost. Consider using subscriptions so that you'd continue to receive an income for as long as people actually want to use the service.

Comment: Exactly, if you may incur in continued backend costs, you should consider other options instead of fixed value app. Maybe “freemium” subscription models (free for just a part of the application functionalities and charge a premium for extra features).

Answer (score 2):

You should check out a company like StackMob that helps you build a complete backend to your mobile app. They provide you with core services you'll want from your backend (secured REST API, Custom Code, Push Notifications, Facebook & Twitter log in and more).  StackMob also helps on the deploy side with clear development and deployment environments along with easy and organized versioning.  And they help with the technical (handle growth/spikes in data/traffic) & business (analytics from the server & client side) scaling of your app.

Answer (score 0):

This is a universal concern surrounding software as a service. There is no correct answer. Just do your best to project costs and price your offering sustainably. Then do your best to keep it open, messaging users if the situation changes.